# Is there any alternate way which I can use instead of position:absolute?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, jscript

I have a search box div, input tag for text and clear image button span within it. I wanted to know what churning position:absolute will cause in IE8?

```
<div class="search-box-div">
    <form onsubmit="return false" name="contentForm">
        <input id="fu-o2ContentCtrl3022348316" class="search-box" type="text"     title="Search Provider">
        <span id="3022348316-clear-sugg-text" class="fu-o2-clear-sugg-text" style="visibility: visible;"></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the css for the classes are:

```
.fu-o2-search {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    width: 65%;
}

.fu-o2-search .search-box-div {
    border: medium none;
    padding: 0;
}

.fu-o2-search .search-box {
    background: url("../images/6428_16.png") no-repeat scroll 0 3px #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #A0A0A0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: 94%;
}

.fu-o2-clear-sugg-text {
    background: url("../images/6457_up_16.png") no-repeat scroll 0 1px #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 17px;
    margin-left: -1.7%;
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 16px;
}
```

Comment: What is currently your issue with IE8???

Comment: @wolff there is no issue with it but it will cause performance issue in our component so I have been asked to find any alternative for this.

Comment: You should reformulate your question, looks like a XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Wolff I am asking if is there any way I can position my clear image button on top of my search text box on the right side. For that even I have posted my CSS if something is missing which can be added to avoid the use of absolute positioning.

Comment: Nothing can replace `position: absolute;` AFAIK without bringing any downside as performance issue